# Rebuild shell script to case

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I want to rebuild my script a little bit to make it more easier for other people. 
I think it will be more easier with case and functions.

```
IP="192.168.123." #$1 is the last number for the ip-address

regExp="^[0-9]+[-,0-9]*$"

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then    
echo "No numbers given "
exit 0                 
fi

if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
    echo "Give numbers to test"
    exit 0               
fi
```

I want to make something like this:

```
 if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then    
    echo "No numbers given "
    # exit 0    --> do I have to write this?

case
-h ) echo "Give numbers to test";   

esac      

    fi
```

Do I have to write that exit?
Are there things to make it easier?

Comment: semi off topic but, have you considered python?

Comment: I only use ubuntu for 2 months, i don't know python :(

Comment: If you're new to Linux, just keep learning shell scripting. You're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If all your statements are inside the `case` then you don't need the exit

```
case "$1" in
  '') echo No numbers given;;
  -h) echo Give numbers to test;;
  *) ...
esac
```